# I want to draw infinite loops in tikzcd (with dotted loops to show that it continues till infinity)?

Tags: tikz-arrows, graphs

I am using tikzcd. I have one vertex and n loops thorugh it. I want first few loops to be solid and later loops to be dotted to signify that there are many more. I am new to latex and don't understand much, so try to present it in a simple manner.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em}}
\tikzset{edge/.style = {->,> = latex'}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (a) at (0,2) {a};
   \path[->] (a) edge [loop left, "$e_{n-1}$"]  (a);
   \path[->] (a) edge [loop right, "$e_1$"]  (a);
   \path[->] (a) edge [loop above, "$e_n$"]  (a);
   \path[->] (a) edge [loop below, "$e_2$"]  (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This is just o4 loops, I want more than 4. I want n such loop at a some of which dotted.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and an image (also a photo of something drawn by hand is OK) of the desired result?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Is the above code sufficient

Comment: You say you are using `tikzcd` but the MWE does not. Nothing in that MWE is related to `tikz-cd`, but `tikz-cd` uses features linke this with exatra macros.

Comment: sorry  I hace edited it again,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it might be that you expect something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                quotes}
\tikzset{
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},
       every edge/.append style = {> = stealth, % arrowhead can be changed only on the such way
                                   draw=red, semithick},
                  vertex/.style = {shape=circle, draw, minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=2pt}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
\node   (a) [vertex] {a};
\path[scale=2] % <--- scaled loops size
        (a) edge [loop right, "$e_1$"]
        (a) edge [out=-30, in=-60, distance=5mm, ->, "$e_2$"] (a)
        (a) edge [loop above, "$e_{n-1}$"]
        (a) edge [out= 60, in= 30, distance=5mm, ->, "$e_n$"] (a);
\draw [densely dotted]  (285:1.5em) arc (285:120:1.5em);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes you misunderstood my question , I really need only the 2nd part of your answer. Anyways thank for the answer.

Comment: on the end i didn't misunderstood it :-). your  question was not clear to me :-(.