# I want to label a loop in Tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,2) {a};
\node (b) at (1,3) {b};
\node (c) at (1,1) {c};
\node (d) at (2,3) {d};
\node (e) at (2,1) {e};

\path[->] (a) edge ["f"] (b);
\path[->] (a) edge ["k"] (c);
\path[->] (b) edge ["g"] (d);
\path[->] (c) edge ["l"] (e);
\path[->] (a) edge [loop left] ["A"] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is showing me an error, if I remove the labelling of loop then it works fine

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) on this site, please **always** post full minimal examples instead of sniplets like this. Then it is a lot easier for others to copy and test your code. For example if I add your code to a very simple doc that loads `tikz` the first line with `"f"` will not even compile. (3) for the `loop left` one you probably need `[loop left,"A"]` not two options.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, please edit your previous one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418507/i-want-to-draw-infinite-loops-in-tikzcd-with-dotted-loops-to-show-that-it-conti

Comment: As expected, your code compiles just fine with the change I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

you have two errors:

- `tikz` library `quotes` is missed
- option for `loop left`  had to be merged wit label quotes. instead of it option i would use `out=210, in=150, looseness=5,` (see mwe below)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                quotes% added mised library
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize},% <-- added
                        ]
\node (a) at (0,2) {a};
\node (b) at (1,3) {b};
\node (c) at (1,1) {c};
\node (d) at (2,3) {d};
\node (e) at (2,1) {e};
%
\path[->] % <-- changed to shorter code
    (a) edge ["f"] (b)
    (a) edge ["k"] (c)
    (b) edge ["g"] (d)
    (c) edge ["l"] (e)
    (a) edge [out=210, in=150, looseness=5, "A"] (a);% <-- changed/corrected
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]